# How can I parse a serialized data field in php?

Tags: php, parsing, serialization

I have a serialized data field from Drupal that I can't figure out how to properly parse out. This is an example of the serialized data:

```
a:10:{s:7:"contact";s:1:"1";s:19:"profile_affiliation";s:23:"The Learning Tree, Inc.";s:18:"profile_first_name";s:3:"Ben";s:22:"profile_street_address";s:19:"8718 Terrell Ct. S.";s:12:"profile_city";s:6:"Mobile";s:13:"profile_state";s:2:"AL";s:15:"profile_country";s:3:"USA";s:15:"profile_zipcode";s:5:"36695";s:18:"profile_home_phone";s:10:"2516494420";s:17:"profile_last_name";s:6:"Rogers";}
```

I've gotten this far:

```
$data = serializeddata;
$var = unserialize($data);

foreach ($var as $value) {
    echo $value['profile_first_name'];
}
```

This isn't working as expected. I get these errors:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'profile_first_name'...
```

Maybe there is more work I need to do to parse the unserialized data so I can grab each of these values by name. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you have invalid `string` which can't be unserialized.

Comment: @pixelsoft Can you please check your string again and update in your post?

Comment: check my answer which work perfectly with details

Comment: I edited my serialized data (I originally mistyped it). It is correct now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this one out with some help. The issue is that you need to repair the data first before parsing.

```
$fixed = preg_replace_callback(
   '/s:([0-9]+):\"(.*?)\";/',
   function ($matches) { return "s:".strlen($matches[2]).':"'.$matches[2].'";';     },
      $data
   );
$original_array=unserialize($fixed);
```

Then you can parse it out:

```
foreach ($original_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key .": ". $value;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = serializeddata;
$var = unserialize($data);

foreach ($var as $value) {
    echo $value['contact'];
}
```

Comment: this will most likely throw a `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`  kind of warning though. As spotted by @sahil-gulati, invalid string :/

Comment: @OldPadawan -> check my answer

Answer (score 0):

check this code. it will work and your serializeddata format is not good. so in this case your code not work
 first your serialize data format need to update

```
$seriliaze = 'a: 7:{s: 7:"contact";i: 1;s: 18:"profile_first_name";s: 5:"John";s: 17:"profile_last_name";s: 6:"Smith";}';
```

to

```
 $seriliaze = 'a:5:{i:1;s:7:"contact";i:2;s:18:"profile_first_name";i:3;s:4:"John";i:4;s:17:"profile_last_name";i:5;s:5:"Smith";}';
```

then section replace

```
1. a: 7 -> a:5 // cause total 5 data
2. add index for every section like i:1;s:7:"contact";
3. s: 5:"John"; -> s:4:"John"; // cause 4 length
4. s: 6:"Smith"; -> s:5:"Smith"; // cause 5 length
```

after this section update your code will work, check now

```
<?php
$seriliaze = 'a:5:{i:1;s:7:"contact";i:2;s:18:"profile_first_name";i:3;s:4:"John";i:4;s:17:"profile_last_name";i:5;s:5:"Smith";}';
$unserialize = unserialize($seriliaze);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unserialize);
```

then output is:

```
   Array
(
    [1] => contact
    [2] => profile_first_name
    [3] => John
    [4] => profile_last_name
    [5] => Smith
)
```

if you get data then use this code

```
  $i = 0;
  $j = 0;
  $format_value = '';
  foreach ($unserialize as $value) {
      $i++;
      if($i == 1){
        continue;
      }
      if($j < 2){
        $j++;
        if($j == 1 ){
           $format_value .= $value.' : ';
        } else {
           $format_value .= $value;
        }

      }
      if( $j== 2){
       $j =0;
        echo $format_value;
        $format_value = '';
      echo "<br>";
      }

  }
```

then output is :

```
profile_first_name : John
profile_last_name : Smith
```

Comment: This is great! The only thing now is how the data is displayed. I want to be displaying the data like: key: value (profile_first_name: John)

Comment: You want to this only this json data?

Comment: I want to parse through the array so that I can detect each value like this:
key: value. So I should be able to know what the "profile_first_name" and "profile_last_name" values are.

Comment: Hello @Shafiquel Islam, When I use your code with my serialized data in my original post, it does not render correctly.

Comment: it is working fine. run my code then check . i think it is other problem

Comment: No, it is not working fine with this data: a:10:{s:7:"contact";s:1:"1";s:19:"profile_affiliation";s:23:"University, Inc.";s:18:"profile_first_name";s:3:"Ben";s:22:"profile_street_address";s:19:"8718 Tot Ave. S.";s:12:"profile_city";s:6:"Mobile";s:13:"profile_state";s:2:"AL";s:15:"profile_country";s:3:"USA";s:15:"profile_zipcode";s:5:"36695";s:18:"profile_home_phone";s:10:"2599494420";s:17:"profile_last_name";s:6:"Powers";}

Comment: not working cause again problem in your json data. check your data first

Comment: check this code which working 

<?php
$main_array = array('Math', 'Language', 'Science');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($main_array);
$serialized_data = serialize($main_array);
echo  'Serialized data : '.$serialized_data . '<br>';

$unserialize = unserialize($serialized_data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($unserialize);
?>